# Tableau: Global Dimension using Fixed - Linked to Parameter

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have the following Table in Tableau server and using USERNAME() will return the 'Employee' value.

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| Employee | Manager | Job Role |
+----------+---------+----------+
| jdoe     | hwu     | Analyst  |
| anon     | hwu     | IT       |
| jlaw     | hwu     | Analyst  |
| kreaves  | bpitt   | Analyst  |
| jlopez   | bpitt   | IT       |
| mmoss    | bpitt   | IT       |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

**Goal:** Find users similar to self based on parameter. Parameter values - Manager, Job Role.

**Example:** My USERNAME() is jdoe.
When I choose the parameter value 'Manager', tableau filters and gives a result of employees under 'hwu' only, as shown below.

```
+----------+
| Employee |
+----------+
| jdoe     |
| anon     |
| jlaw     |
+----------+
```

Similarly, when Job Role is selected, it filters to a list of users with the job role 'Analyst', as shown below.

```
+----------+
| Employee |
+----------+
| jdoe     |
| jlaw     |
| kreaves  |
+----------+
```

I know there should be a simple solution to this using LOD calculations, but I am stumped on how to approach this!

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Could you give us an example of what it should be doing?

Comment: @lampbob I hope these examples provide some clarity.

Comment: still not clear what you want to happen differently

Comment: @AlexBlakemore The grouping varies based on Job Role and Manager. When parameter value 'Job Role' is selected, it lists out all users with my Job Role, similarly when 'Manager' is selected, it lists out all users with my Manger.

Answer (score 0):

Make a calculated field that uses UserName(), your parameter and whatever fields are needed that produces a boolean value. Use that field to filter for the rows of interest.

For example, create a calculated field called [Value of Interest]
`if [My Param] = "Manager" then [Manager] else [Job Role] end`

And another calculated field  called [My Value of Interest] `{ min(if [Employee] = username() then [Value of Interest] end) }` That's your LOD calc.

Now you can put a calc on the filter shelf that tests whether `[My Value of Interest] = [Value of Interest]`

I'm not at place where I can test this but it should get you started

Comment: How do I get the corresponding ManagerName/JobRole to USERNAME()? I feel LOD calculations should be used for this, but I am not sure how.